# How to find which Process is causing High CPU usage

Tags: linux, terminal, process, cpu

Is there any way to find out from terminal which process is causing high CPU Usage ?

It would also be useful to order processes in descending order of cpu Usage

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`top` will display what is using your CPU. If you have it installed, `htop` allows you more fine-grained control, including filtering by—in your case—CPU

Comment: Top is often less than useful. First because processes often fluctuate - it's not unusual to see process that is completely occupying the cpu occasionally flicker to 0% in top, and if you have multiple intensive processes running they can alternate, taking turns to use 100% while the other uses 0%, making it hard to read. Also, sometimes the numbers are just strange - e.g. right now my top is reporting that all individual processes are using 0% cpu, but the total is 52% - so which one is doing it?

Answer (score 56):

```
ps -eo pcpu,pid,user,args | tail -n +2 | sort -k1 -r -n | head -10
```

Works for me, show the top 10 cpu using threads, sorted numerically

Comment: The title line `%CPU    PID USER     COMMAND` sometimes will be printed, as one of the top 10 :)

Answer (score 9):

In addition to `ps` and `top` commands, you can also run `vmstat` to figure out what is happening in terms of CPU, memory usage on the system, i.e.:

```
vmstat 1 100
```

With the above, you get 100 samples a second apart of various stats. When the `r` or `b` column has a number (higher = more resources used) there is a script that is blocking. `r` is CPU, `b` is generally IO blocking such as disk or network.

Example output:

```
$ vmstat 1 100
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0      0 288700  17592 1920048    0    0  4482  3297   47  155  8  2 78 12  0
 0  0      0 268420  17904 1920584    0    0   788    36 4095 4759 11  3 85  1  0
 0  0      0 269916  17940 1920868    0    0   108   560 6969 7280 11  2 86  1  1
 3  0      0 267684  18196 1921304    0    0   256     0 5934 6094  9  2 90  0  0
 0  0      0 257800  18196 1921528    0    0     0     0 5412 5508 10  1 89  0  1
 1  0      0 257368  18196 1922028    0    0     0     0 5852 6046  9  1 89  0  1
 0  0      0 256872  18200 1922236    0    0     0     0 5345 5566  9  1 90  0  0
 0  0      0 256688  18208 1922292    0    0     0  1788 5388 5602  7  2 90  1  1
 0  0      0 256520  18208 1922684    0    0     0     0 5387 5557  8  1 91  0  0
 1  0      0 255788  18208 1923024    0    0     0     0 4992 5363 10  1 89  0  1
 1  0      0 255392  18208 1923456    0    0     0     0 5027 5145 13  1 86  0  0
 0  0      0 254980  18208 1923792    0    0     0     0 5042 5082 21  1 77  0  1
 0  0      0 254452  18216 1924092    0    0     0  1848 5481 5695  7  1 91  1  1
 0  0      0 254416  18216 1924268    0    0     0     0 4947 5250  7  1 92  0  0
 1  0      0 253732  18216 1924616    0    0     0     0 5180 5383  8  2 90  0  1
 0  0      0 253584  18216 1924912    0    0    12     0 4464 4623  8  1 91  0  0
 0  0      0 243496  18216 1925224    0    0     0     0 5507 5700  9  1 90  0  1
 0  0      0 243008  18224 1925504    0    0     0  1356 5070 5345  8  1 90  0  1
 1  0      0 243220  18228 1925676    0    0     0     0 6241 6533 11  2 87  0  0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use `ps xo pid,cmd --sort=%cmd | tail -1`, but `top` will show in real time.

Answer (score 2):

"[htop](https://github.com/hishamhm/htop)" is similar to top, but has a "colourful text-based graphical" display of your CPUs, and also displays a tree structure to processes, so you know a process has a child and how many.

It also displays laptop battery power and whether it's charging - I didn't know that before!