# My Dell Fan running high after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, fan

I have a Dell XPS 15 9500. I have been happily using 18.04 but keep getting told I need to update to 20.04. I've upgraded, but now the fan seems to be running high pretty much all the time, even when the computer is doing nothing / asleep.

Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: `keep getting told I need to update` ... by who?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find which Process is causing High CPU usage](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20483/how-to-find-which-process-is-causing-high-cpu-usage)

Comment: @jsotola when I post on a forum about any minor issue that I'm having, and mention that I have Ubuntu 18.04, someone usually responds telling me that I need to upgrade to 20.04 and my problems will disappear. That hasn't been the case unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your laptop is actually running hot, `top` or `htop` will help you track down what process are using a ton of CPU, which will be a good first troubleshooting step.  The way you've phrased it is unclear if it's hot or the fans are on when they don't need to be.